# Resources to understand the math behind diffusion models

Tags: deep-learning, generative-model, probability-theory, diffusion-models

I started learning about diffusion models, but I couldn't follow the math proofs (probability distribution terms and other stuff), is there any sources you suggest to understand what they're talking about?

my background on these probability terms is quite limited, I learned only the introduction stuff, so only general definition.

If you could suggest me some resources that takes into account the deep learning side and also other deep generative models that would be a plus.